# How to make a bunch of inputs disappear when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to make a post sumbit page like reddit's but then i got a problem when trying to make the buttons work as expected for example: if i click the "post" button it will show a text area then when I click the "image & video" button it will delete the text area element and replaces it with an input (with attribute of `type="file"` ) It was working all fine until i added a third button that adds another input and works the same way, it didn't work as expected and it couldn't delete the previous inputs when clicked (the first two buttons are still working well but also they can't delete the third button's input)
so here is the code

```js
//Normal text post part
document.getElementById('textarea-btn').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.target.disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('media').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('link-btn').disabled = false;
    let textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textarea.setAttribute('class', 'post-data');
    textarea.setAttribute('id', 'textarea');
    textarea.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Text (optional)');
    document.querySelector('.post-content').appendChild(textarea);
    
    //removing other inputs
    let file = document.getElementById('file');
    let link = document.getElementById('link')
    document.querySelector('.post-content').removeChild(file);
    document.querySelector('.post-content').removeChild(link);
});
    
//media post section
document.getElementById('media').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.target.disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('textarea-btn').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('link-btn').disabled = false;
    let file = document.createElement('input');
    file.setAttribute('class', 'post-data');
    file.setAttribute('id', 'file');
    file.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    document.querySelector('.post-content').appendChild(file);
    
    //removing other inputs
    let textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
    let link = document.getElementById('link');
    document.querySelector('.post-content').removeChild(textarea);
    document.querySelector('.post-content').removeChild(link);
});
    
//Link section
document.getElementById('link-btn').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.target.disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('textarea-btn').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('media').disabled = false;
    let link = document.createElement('input');
    link.setAttribute('class', 'title-text');
    link.setAttribute('id', 'link');
    link.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    link.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Link');
    document.querySelector('.post-content').appendChild(link);
    
    //removing other inputs
    let file = document.getElementById('file');
    let textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
    document.querySelector('.post-content').removeChild(file);
    document.querySelector('.post-content').removeChild(textarea);
})
```

```html
<div id="post-creator" class="creator-container">
    <div class="post-type">
        <button class="text-post" id="textarea-btn">Post</button>
        <button class="media-post" id="media">Image & video</button>
        <button class="link-post" id="link-btn">Link</button>
    </div>
    <div class="post-title">
        <input type="text" class="title-text" name="post-title" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="post-content">

    </div>
    <div class="post-footer">
        <div class="spoiler">Spoiler</div>
        <div class="nsfw">NSFW</div>
        <button class="post">post</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like there are console errors when clicking the buttons.

Comment: There's no `id="file"` or `id="textarea"` in the HTML, so `removeChild(file)` and `removeChild(textarea)` get errors.

Comment: those ids are generated by js when clicking the buttons

Answer (score 0):

The code shows errors on **removeChild** because it can not find the node under the element you are trying to remove. I would say try to check if the element exists before removing it.

Try running the following code if it works

```
<script>
el = document.getElementById('textarea-btn');
if(el)
{
    //Normal text post part
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.target.disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('media').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('link-btn').disabled = false;
    let textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textarea.setAttribute('class', 'post-data');
    textarea.setAttribute('id', 'textarea');
    textarea.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Text (optional)');
    document.querySelector('.post-content').appendChild(textarea);

    //removing other inputs
    let _file = document.getElementById('file');
    let _link = document.getElementById('link')

     let _div = document.querySelector('.post-content');
    if(_div.contains(_file)){
        _div.removeChild(_file);
    }
     if(_div.contains(_link)){
        _div.removeChild(_link);
    }

  });

}

el = document.getElementById('media');

if(el)
{  

    //media post section
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.target.disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('textarea-btn').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('link-btn').disabled = false;
    let file = document.createElement('input');
    file.setAttribute('class', 'post-data');
    file.setAttribute('id', 'file');
    file.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    document.querySelector('.post-content').appendChild(file);

    //removing other inputs
    let _textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
    let _link = document.getElementById('link');

    let _div = document.querySelector('.post-content');
    if(_div.contains(_textarea)){
        _div.removeChild(_textarea);
    }
     if(_div.contains(_link)){
        _div.removeChild(_link);
    }
  });
}


el = document.getElementById('link-btn');
if(el)
{
    //Link section
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.target.disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('textarea-btn').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('media').disabled = false;
    let link = document.createElement('input');
    link.setAttribute('class', 'title-text');
    link.setAttribute('id', 'link');
    link.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    link.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Link');
    document.querySelector('.post-content').appendChild(link);

    //removing other inputs
    let _file = document.getElementById('file');
    let _textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

     let _div = document.querySelector('.post-content');
    if(_div.contains(_file)){
        _div.removeChild(_file);
    }
     if(_div.contains(_textarea)){
        _div.removeChild(_textarea);
    }
});
}
</script>
```